# sftp is not working in cron or crontab but ftp works fine

Tags: unix, ftp, cron, sftp

i have created a script file `transfer.sh` which `ftp` a `test.txt` file to server, now i have made the entry of script file in `crontab`, if i use `ftp` to transfer the file it works fine in crontab, when i use `sftp` instead of ftp it is not working in cron tab, but when i manually run the transfer.sh script it works fine and transfer the file using `sftp` to the server. i don't see any error in log.

my script `transfer.sh` script is

```
sftp user/pass@host.com <<END_SCRIPT
cd /mydir
put test.txt
bye
END_SCRIPT
```

Comment: Did you try to redirect the output to a file? What does it output?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl how to redirect output to file?

Comment: `... END_SCRIPT > /somepath/sftp.out`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl sftp.out file is not genereted, i have tried

Comment: So I assume the `transfer.sh` is not even run, right? What's your crontab entry?

Comment: script is working, that test.txt file is generated throgh this script

Comment: file test.txt is not transferred to server using sftp command if put ftp place of sftp it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crontab was not able to find `sftp` utility on unix server, there are two ways to resolve the problem.

1. Append your `PATH` environment variable with `sftp` path
2. Use sftp command with absolute path in your script

   example.

   /usr/localcw/opt/ssh/bin/sftp user/pass@host.com

how to find `sftp` absolute path, below is example

```
$which sftp
/usr/localcw/bin/sftp
```

go to `/usr/localcw/bin` location

```
$cd /usr/localcw/bin
```

hit `ls -lrt sftp`

```
/usr/localcw/bin $ls -lsrt sftp
0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          19 Apr 11  2012 sftp -> ../opt/ssh/bin/sftp
```

here again its a soft link to `../opt/ssh/bin/sftp`, now `cd` to `../opt/sh/bin`

```
/usr/localcw/bin $ cd ../opt/ssh/bin
```

now pwd is your `sftp` absolute path

```
/usr/localcw/opt/ssh/bin $ pwd
/usr/localcw/opt/ssh/bin
```

Use this path with sftp command

Comment: Another way to find the real path of a file: `realpath $(which sftp)`. Requires a modern system.